# How to jump to an open terminal with all other windows minimized?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments, shortcuts

I would like to create a shortcut to minimize all windows and access to my -opened- terminal. I know the command ctrl+super+D to minimize every windows, but I want a simplest way. (ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 3):

The script below can do what you want. Usage is very simple: bind this to a keyboard shortcut and give it the window class of the terminal. Follow the steps below

#### 1. Save the file

Preferably, it should be saved in your home folder under `~/bin` directory. If you don't have that directory, create it.

Ensure the script has executable permissions with `chmod +x` like so.

```
 $ chmod +x ~/bin/get_terminal.py
```

#### 2. Figure out the WM_CLASS of your terminal.

Use `xprop` command to do so (it will let you select the window you want to check by changing your cursor into x symbol):

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS                                                               
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal-server", "Gnome-terminal"
```

Any of the resulting strings will do.

#### 3. Bind to keyboard shortcut

Under  System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom. Add the following entry:

[image]

The command used there is :

```
python3 /home/xieerqi/bin/get_terminal.py "Gnome-terminal"
```

Notice that I gave it full path and the WM_CLASS is quoted

The keyboard shortcut I've set is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, but you are free to use other keybindings as well.

#### Script Source

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#from __future__ import print_function
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk
import subprocess
import time
import os
import sys

def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ Reusable function for running external commands """
    new_env = dict(os.environ)
    new_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist, env=new_env)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
         print('FAIL:' + repr(cmdline))
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout

def main():

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
       sys.stderr.write("REQUIRES WM_CLASS\n")
       sys.exit(1)

    screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
    for window in screen.get_window_stack():
        xid = int(window.get_xid())
        wm_class = run_cmd(['xprop','-notype','WM_CLASS','-id',str(xid)])
        if sys.argv[1] in wm_class.decode():
            window.focus(int(time.time()))
            window.process_all_updates()
        else:
            window.iconify()
            window.process_all_updates()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---